# Exercise 13 on p.38 in Exercises 2B in "Measure, Integration & Real Analysis" by Sheldon Axler. Is my proof ok?

Tags: solution-verification, measurable-functions

I am reading "Measure, Integration & Real Analysis" by Sheldon Axler.
The following exercise is Exercise 13 on p.38 in Exercises 2B in this book.

> Exercise 13
> Suppose $(X,\mathcal{S})$ is a measurable space, $E_1,\dots,E_n$ are disjoint subsets of $X$, and $c_1,\dots,c_n$ are distinct nonzero real numbers. Prove that $c_1\chi_{E_1}+\dots+c_n\chi_{E_n}$ is an $\mathcal{S}$-measurable function if and only if $E_1,\dots,E_n\in\mathcal{S}.$

My proof is here:

> Suppose $E_1,\dots,E_n\in\mathcal{S}.$
> Let $f:=c_1\chi_{E_1}+\dots+c_n\chi_{E_n}.$
> Let $c_0:=0.$
> Let $E_0:=X\setminus (E_1\cup\dots\cup E_n).$
> Then, $E_0\in\mathcal{S}.$
> Let $B$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}.$
> Let $I_B:=\{i\in\{0,1,\dots,n\}:c_i\in B\}.$
> Then, $f^{-1}(B)=\bigcup_{i\in I_B} E_i\in\mathcal{S}.$
> So, $f$ is an $\mathcal{S}$-measurable function.
> Conversely, suppose $f$ is an $\mathcal{S}$-measurable function.
> Let $i\in\{0,1,\dots,n\}.$
> $\{c_i\}$ is a Borel set because $\{c_i\}$ is closed.
> So, $E_i=f^{-1}(\{c_i\})\in\mathcal{S}.$
> So, $E_1,\dots,E_n\in\mathcal{S}.$

I guess my proof is ok, but I fear situations where I think I am right but in reality I am wrong.

Is my proof ok?

Comment: Do you know the proof of $\chi_{E}$ is measurable iff $E$ is measurable.

Comment: Yes. The author wrote the proof in 2.38 Example on p.31 in the book.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Thank you very much for your hint. If $\chi_{E_1},\dots,\chi_{E_n}$ are $\mathcal{S}$-measurable functions, then $c_1\chi_{E_1}+\dots+c_n\chi_{E_n}$ is an $\mathcal{S}$-measurable function by 2.44 on p.34 and by 2.46 on p.35.